# Copy programs from one disk to another

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, copying

I wish to copy all data and progams from one disk (disk 1, e:) to another disk (disk 2, f:) and then rename the drive letter of disk 2 to e:. Will the programs which i copied from disk 1 to disk 2 continue to work if i do this?

**Current situation**

- DISK 1 (c:) -> OS
- DISK 1 (e:) -> programs and data
- DISK 2 (f:) -> data

**New situation**

- DISK 1 (c:) -> OS
- DISK 2 (e:) -> programs and data

Comment: Maybe.  How do you intend on copying the data?

Comment: While the os is running simply copying (ctrl c, ctrl v) the data from disk to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seems to be a problem as long as you keep the same permissions on the copied files (look at robocopy for example).

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what i am looking for. However i am not familiar with could you please indicate whether this syntac is correct:
    ROBOCOPY E:\ F:\ /e /z /copyall /dcopy:t

Comment: Sorry i mean: ROBOCOPY E:\ F:\ /e /zb /copyall /dcopy:t

Comment: That seems correct to me. Even if I don't know the /b option but it might be useful to avoid access issues.

Comment: For anyone who is interested: Tested the proposed solution and it works.